JSON schema $id scoping discrepencies
Given the following schema definition:
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://fobar.json",
  "type": "object",
  "$defs": {
    "one": {
      "$id": "/one",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "two": {
      "$id": "a/sub/schema.json",
      "properties": {
        "one": {
          "$id": "/one",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "$ref": "one"
    }
  }
}

When I use ajv to compile this, I get an error "http://foobar.json/one" resolves to more than one schema Which I believe to be the correct error. https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ however, fails to give an error on this. It will give a warning, if I add, "b": {"$ref": "a/sub/schema.json"} after the a property

It's because in http://fobar.json, fobar.json is the domain.  Paths are resolved on the domain.
Additionally, the slash on /one means "start from the root of the domain."

/one is a path on the fobar.json domain to give you http://fobar.json/one (for both cases, causing your error)
a/sub/schema.json gives http://fobar.json/a/sub/schema.json

If you want the /one nested under the two property to resolve to http://fobar.json/a/sub/one (which is what it sounds like you want), you'll need to lose the slash and just use one for the $id there.

That is how I read it. Meaning https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ is failing to report a valid schema problem.

It's not technically an invalid schema, it's just ambiguous. It's like how { "a": 1, "a": 2 } isn't technically invalid JSON. Implementations aren't required to report this as an error. Ajv tries to do some linting checks beyond what is required. Unfortunately, they don't distinguish between their custom linting errors and actual specification errors which causes a lot of confusion.

Additional context: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ is powered by Newtonsoft.Json.Schema (.Net), not ajv.
